# JSON feed in UTF-8 without byte order marker

Tags: json, wcf, api, encoding, byte-order-mark

I have an WCF application written in C# that deliver my data in JSON or XML, depending on what the user asks for in the query string.  Here is a quick snippet of my code that delivers the data:

```
Encoding utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);
return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(data, "application/json", utf8);
```

When I deliver the data using above method, the special characters are all messed up.  So Chávez looks like ChÃ¡vez.  On the other hand, if I create the utf8 variable above with the BOM or use the enum (Encoding.UTF8), the special characters are working fine.  But then, some of my consumers are complaining that their code is throwing exception when consuming my API.  This of course is happening because of the BOM in the feed.  Is there a way for me to correctly display the special characters without the BOM in the feed?

Comment: Have you tried the content type `application/json; charset=utf-8` instead of `application/json` ?

Comment: The only legal encodings for json are UTF-8/16/32 with UTF-8 being a de facto standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the output is correct, but whatever you are using to display it expects ANSI encoded text. ChÃ¡vez is what you get when you encode Chávez in UTF-8 and interpret the result as if it was Latin 1.

Comment: I am merely viewing it in a browser and devices expecting it in UTF8. If I am to get only ChÃ¡vez then why does it display correctly when the BOM is added. Thanks.

Comment: A web browser? You have to send the appropriate content-type header, like `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8` to make it interpret the document in UTF-8. When you send a BOM you are likely triggering the browser's automatic encoding detection algorithm.

Comment: For some reason, I was expecting the CreateTextResponse method to use the encoding type to add the content-type header. In this case, I had to specify it in the contentType parameter that it is utf-8. After adding the full content-type, I was able to get correct results.